# date_format with sequelize mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize for my backend and I want to add a where condition with `YYYY-mm-dd`

In mysql we use `date_format(dateCreated, "%d-%m-%Y")`.

But how to achieve it in Sequelize. I searched all over the google but nothing helped me out

My present Sequelize query. I want to get data of `dateCreated = '2020-05-31'`.

```
const apartmentOrdersData = await apartments_order.findAll(
        {
            where: { apid: req.body.apid }, group: ['apcid'],
            attributes: ['apcid', [sequelize.fn('sum', sequelize.col('totalCost')), 'total_amount'],],
            include: [apartments_child]
        });
```

My model:

```
    const { DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize');
    const sequelize = require('../../../mysql_connection/sequilize');
    const admins = require('./admins');
    const apartments_child = require('./apartments_child');

    class apartments_order extends Model { }

    apartments_order.init({
        // Model attributes are defined here
        apoid: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        invoiceNo: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        apid: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        apcid: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        apcbid: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        totalCost: {
            type: DataTypes.DECIMAL
        },
        dateCreated: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE
        },
        dateUpdated: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE
        },
        createdBy: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        updatedBy: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        status: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        }
    }, {
        sequelize,
        timestamps: false,
        logging: false,
        tableName: 'apartments_order'
    });

    apartments_order.hasOne(admins, { foreignKey: 'aid', sourceKey: 'createdBy' });
    apartments_order.hasOne(apartments_child, { foreignKey: 'apcid', sourceKey: 'apcid' });

    module.exports = apartments_order;
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can do is use a setter and getter for the columns.

Follow an example (on your field declaration, you can manipulate the data inside `getter()` and `setter()`:

```
dateUpdated: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    defaultValue: '[]',
    get() {
        const d = this.getDataValue('dateUpdated');
        return format(d, 'Y-m-d');

    },
    set(value) {
        return this.setDataValue('dateUpdated', format(value, <your-format-here>)
    },
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
},
```